# Slice between two strings (email + word)

Tags: text-processing, email, cygwin

I need a way to slice everything after an email appears and before certain text appears.

Example formats are shown here:

```
email@email.com:0:3rw3e:weofkew:StackOverflow=
email@email.com:19.2132.1:StackOverflow=
```

Format needed would be:

```
email@email.com:StackOverflow= (followded by everything else on the line).
```

So essentially slicing after an email appears, and before `StackOverflow=` appears.

Notes: All emails are unique, it's not literally `email@email.com`

Comment: Could you please include examples in your question?

Comment: I did in the hastebin below, I assumed posting examples here would make the post untidy.

Comment: The preference is for self-contained questions and answers, in case the external link goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/(@[^:]+:).*(StackOverflow=)/\1\2/' input.txt
```

### Explanation

- `sed -r 's/foo/bar/' input.txt`: use sed with extended regular expressions, replacing pattern `foo` with `bar`, for file `input.txt`.
- `(@[^:]+:).*(StackOverflow=)`: match from the `@` in the email address, which is followed by 1 or more non-`:` characters (`[^:]+`). This is then followed by a `:`. Capture this all in the first capturing groups with `()`. This is followed by a number of characters `.*`, then `StackOverflow=`, which we also capture in a group `()`.
- `/1/2`: replace this expression with the partial email address (the first capturing group above), skip the part in between, then followed by the second capturing group.

N.B. this makes a lot of assumptions about the format of the input file, e.g. the format of the email address, the number of `@` and `StackOverflow=` per line, etc.

Comment: I appreciate the time you've spent on this, thankyou so much.

Comment: Glad I could help @StackStackAndStack. If this answers your question, you can click the tick on the left of the answer (and upvote with the up arrow if you feel that is appropriate). Welcome to U/L!